# css transition effects on background AND text on hover

Tags: css, transition

I am trying to make the transition effect to work on both text and background on hover of the box but my result so far is two seperate effects. when i hover the box the transition on bg is working fine but the effect of the text is happening only when i hover the text itself.
I would like to apply the color change when by hovering in the whole box not have to hover the text also.
I need the bG color to change from black to white and the Title to change from white to black!

my css is

```css
.stylish-popular-widget
{
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 
}
.stylish-popular-widget img
{
 height: 150px;
 max-width: 100%;
}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text
{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 bottom: 0;
 top: 65%; /*adjust BG start position*/
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 10px;
 moz-transition: 1s;
 ms-transition: 1s;
 o-transition: 1s;
 transition: 1s;
 webkit-transition: 1s;
}
 
}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3
{
 color: #FF0000 !important;
 
}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3 a
{
 color: #fff !important;
 font-size: 25px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 
 
}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3 a:hover 
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000 !important;
 
}

.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3 :hover 
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000 !important;
 
}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text span.date
{
 color: rgba(59,59,59,1);
 font-size: 11px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 
}
.stylish-popular-widget:hover > .meta-text
{
 background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);  
 top:inherit;
    top: 0;
  
}
```

```html
    <?php ?>
    
    <div class="stylish-popular-widget">
     <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail('popular_posts_img'); ?>
     <div class="meta-text">
      <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
      TEST</h3>
      <span class="date">thstrhsthths</span></a>
     </div>
     </a>
    </div>
    
   <?php
```

Comment: It will be easier if you gave an online example via jsfiddle or codepen. Anyway, you need to either change the `:hover` to be on the wrapping block element instead of on the anchor (a) tag, OR you could change the anchor to be a block element by adding `display: block` to the anchor, and then you could give it dimensions.

Comment: Thank you verry much for your answer!
I am new with coding and I am sorry for all my questions and mistakes...

Can you give me an example with some solution implemented?

Comment: I hope this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/msyLj79n/
it's just one example, but there are many different ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks Narxx i solved the problem :))

Comment: Yes, I see. That was the first suggestion I gave you: "you need to either change the :hover to be on the wrapping block element instead of on the anchor". This is exactly what you did :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
.stylish-popular-widget:hover .meta-text h3 a {
  color: black!important;
}
```

**[Live jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/oa21qunf/)**

Comment: HEYYYYYY its working!!!! can you explain me what was the problem?
I am new with coding and it took me all night trying to find how to do it!

Comment: your welcome, you didn't have any problem. you should add this rule, but how it works? , you should use `hover` on your wrapper that you want to hover effect happen, that in your code is `.stylish-popular-widget:hover` , then write your target, that in your code is `.meta-text h3 a` but you need to override color because it took before, then you should use `important` .

Answer (score 0):

```
}
.stylish-popular-widget img
{
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text
{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  color:white;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 65%; /*adjust BG start position*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    moz-transition: 1s;
    ms-transition: 1s;
    o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    webkit-transition: 1s;
}

}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3
{

}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3 a
{
    color: inherit !important;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;


}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3 a:hover 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit !important;

}

.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text :hover 
{
    text-decoration: none;
  color:black;

}
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text span.date
{
    color: rgba(59,59,59,1);
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 30px;

}
.stylish-popular-widget:hover > .meta-text
{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);       
    top:inherit;
    top: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="stylish-popular-widget">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail('popular_posts_img'); ?>
                    <div class="meta-text">
                        <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                        TEST</h3>
                        <span class="date">thstrhsthths</span></a>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Something like this? Its the meta-text that controls the colours of your text here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need multiple `:hover`-s to do this. You can use inheritance, depending on your design:

```
.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    bottom: 0;
    top: 65%; /*adjust BG start position*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    moz-transition: 1s;
    ms-transition: 1s;
    o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    webkit-transition: 1s;
    color: #fff;
}

.stylish-popular-widget .meta-text h3 a {
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: inherit;  
}


.stylish-popular-widget:hover > .meta-text {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);       
    top: 0;
    color: black;
}
```

And you probably don't need all those `!important` declarations.